# Deleting all columns except columns with certain headings

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to format exported data and need to delete several columns. I want to keep columns with certain headings. For convenience if I have 15 columns and want to keep columns with the following headings;

State
City
Name
Client
Product

My concern is that the data I am exporting can change and columns could be added in the future. I want to be able to filter out unwanted columns and just keep the aforementioned columns.

Edit: I am using Excel and I have never written a line of code before in my life. Ever.

Comment: Excel? Access? Which program are you using?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this one.

Iterate over the columns in reverse order, check the headers in a Select Case, and delete as needed.

```
Sub deleteIrrelevantColumns()
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    Dim columnHeading As String

    ActiveSheet.Columns("L").Delete

    For currentColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1

        columnHeading = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value

        'CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP THE COLUMN
        Select Case columnHeading
            Case "State", "City", "Name", "Client", "Product"
                'Do nothing
            Case Else
                'Delete if the cell doesn't contain "Homer"
                If Instr(1, _
                   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value, _
                   "Homer",vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then

                    ActiveSheet.Columns(currentColumn).Delete

                End If
        End Select
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! So far this is working really well. Is there a way to incorporate something in the "check whether to keep column" section that can detect whether a particular word is in the column heading?  I realized that I have a column heading that reads "Product Type/Product Category", but it is separated into two lines. At first I tried to add;
Cells.Select
With Selection
     .WrapText = False
End With

And then use your code. But it isn't detecting the Heading "Product Type/Product Category" and it keeps deleting it.

Comment: You can use the `Instr` function to check for the presence of a word/string within a string.

Comment: No problem. Here's an example of that function in use: `Instr(1, "Marge and Homer Simpson","Homer",vbBinaryCompare)`  a value of `0` means the search was not found, any value other than 0 means that the search was found.

Comment: How would I incorporate that into your Select Case code?
So, say Homer/Simpson was the column heading and I wanted to keep that column?

Comment: @Al Grant sorry I've no idea. probably it's unnecessary remnant from whatever I was doing to debug this at the time, but that was nearly six years ago lol.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing we're talking Excel here.
If so iterating through your columns with a while loop and deciding to keep or not to keep should do the trick.

```
Sub deleteIrrelevantColumns()
    Dim keepColumn As Boolean
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    Dim columnHeading As String

    currentColumn = 1
    While currentColumn <= ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        columnHeading = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value

        'CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP THE COLUMN
        keepColumn = False
        If columnHeading = "State" Then keepColumn = True
        If columnHeading = "City" Then keepColumn = True
        If columnHeading = "Name" Then keepColumn = True
        If columnHeading = "Client" Then keepColumn = True
        If columnHeading = "Product" Then keepColumn = True


        If keepColumn Then
        'IF YES THEN SKIP TO THE NEXT COLUMN,
            currentColumn = currentColumn + 1
        Else
        'IF NO DELETE THE COLUMN
            ActiveSheet.Columns(currentColumn).Delete
        End If

        'LASTLY AN ESCAPE IN CASE THE SHEET HAS NO COLUMNS LEFT
        If (ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address = "$A$1") And (ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1").Text = "") Then Exit Sub
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll test it tomorrow. I tagged it "VBA". Was that not clear enough?

Comment: This isn't working. It deletes the first column it encounters that doesn't meet the 'columnheading' criteria and then stops. Running it again will delete the next column heading that doesn't meet the criteria. When it encounters a column heading that was specified it stops and does nothing. Anyone else have any suggestions?

Comment: Strange, it works for me. I must admit that David's solution is a lot neater though.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and this is the code that worked for me. I think it is much simpler.

```
Range("A1").Select

Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

    If ActiveCell.Value = "Forecast Status" _
        Or ActiveCell.Value = "Amount " _
        Or ActiveCell.Value = "Service Booking Value " _
        Or ActiveCell.Value = "Transaction Number" _
        Or ActiveCell.Value = "Last Modified by" _
        Or ActiveCell.Value = "Last Modified Date" _
        Or ActiveCell.Value = "T# Comparison" _
        Or ActiveCell.Value = "Amount Comparison" _
        Or ActiveCell.Value = "Forecast Status Comparison" _
        Or ActiveCell.Value = "First Ship Date Comparison" Then

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

    Else

        ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        Selection.End(xlUp).Select

    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Yeah, that's gonna be an "error" on the 'much simpler' statement.