# VBA delete columns in a consistently exported sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am wondering if there is some easy lines of code that will allow me to loop through a spreadsheet and only keep columns with certain headers. I would like to use the code in a macro that runs on an exported csv that I have that is exported daily. I know that it is possible, just not sure how the loop will work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting all columns except columns with certain headings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597841/deleting-all-columns-except-columns-with-certain-headings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go! You can also make this into a form that will allow you to type in columns. I will let you figure that out yourself though.

here is the code:

```
Dim currentColumn As Integer
Dim columnHeading As String

For currentColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.count To 1 Step -1
    columnHeading = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value
    'CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP THE COLUMN
    Select Case columnHeading
        Case "header1name", "header2name", "header3name"
            'The columns with these headers will be kept
        Case Else
                ActiveSheet.Columns(currentColumn).Delete
    End Select
Next
```

I will post the form if you would like!

Comment: great, exactly what i needed. thanks for speedy reply!