# Deleting columns that don't have certain string

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a data clean up project in **Excel** and working to build a macro that cleans up and deletes out unnecessary columns in a report.

I'm having issues looping through the columns to delete columns that don't have certain header text (I have 3 separate strings that I am looking to find and not delete).

I found a previous question that helped me get started [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597841/deleting-all-columns-except-columns-with-certain-headings/16610207#16610207?newreg=afe9f6fc34b448c2b1beba455d10a270).

How would I go about expanding this code to take into account multiple strings?

The code I attempted is below.

```
Dim currentColumn As Integer
Dim columnHeading As String

For currentColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1

    columnHeading = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value

    'CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP THE COLUMN
    Select Case columnHeading
        Case "Account Name", "Account ID", "Contract ID", "Delivery Date"
            'Do nothing
        Case Else
            'Delete if the cell doesn't contain "string-"
            If InStr(1, _
               ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value, "string1-" Or "string2-" Or "string3-", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then

                ActiveSheet.Columns(currentColumn).Delete

            End If

    End Select
Next
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't embed an `Or` statement in `InStr` like that - you'll have to use multiple `InStr`s to test against your columns. Also, since you're deleting columns that *contain* the string, you need to check if `InStr` returns a value **greater than** zero, not equal to:

```
Sub Test()

Dim currentColumn As Integer
Dim columnHeading As String

For currentColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1

    columnHeading = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value

    'CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP THE COLUMN
    Select Case columnHeading
        Case "Account Name", "Account ID", "Contract ID", "Delivery Date"
            'Do nothing
        Case Else
            'Delete if the cell doesn't contain "string-"
            If InStr(columnHeading, "string1-") = 0 And _
               InStr(columnHeading, "string2-") = 0 And _
               InStr(columnHeading, "string3-") = 0 Then

                ActiveSheet.Columns(currentColumn).Delete

            End If

    End Select
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: That's good info to know about InStr(). Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I'm looking to delete everything that doesn't contain those strings. So the report I'm getting is a list of sold products with detailed information about them. I'm looking to delete everything out of the report except for the Account information (Account Name, ID, Contract ID, & Delivery Date) which we accomplished at the beginning of this code with the If statements, and then I would like to delete everything that doesn't contain those strings. Does that make sense? Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: @R.Price Edited to use `And` and if it equals 0